# Problemas en angular4 / java : pierde las sesiones de servidor

Tags: java, angular4

Tengo dos peticiones http post, en una el servicio REST guarda la peticion

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpHeaders,HttpResponse } from '@angular/common/http'
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import 'rxjs/Rx';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Usuario } from '../modelo/usuario';
import { MyGuard } from './my-guard.service';
import { APIServiceGetLugares } from '../interfaces/api.service.getlugares';
import { Http, Headers, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
import { HttpClient } from '../request/HttpClient'
@Injectable()
export class AutorizacionService {
  private error:string=null;
    private loggedUser:Usuario=Usuario.ANONIMO;
  private loggedIn:boolean=false;
  private app;
    constructor (private http: Http, private router:Router, private myguard:MyGuard) {
        this.loggedUser=Usuario.ANONIMO;
    this.loggedIn=false;
    this.error=null;

    }

public login(login, password, parent) {
        const headers = new Headers({"Content-Type":"application/json"});
        var serviceUrl = 'http://127.0.0.1:8080/ProgramaHospitalServicios/autenticacion';
        var body:any = {
            "service":"getLogin",
            "params": {
                "login":login,
                "password":password
            }
        };
    this.http.post( serviceUrl,  body,{headers:headers} )
           .subscribe((response) => {
            debugger; 
            if(response.status==200){
              this.loggedIn = true
              debugger;
              this.loggedUser = this.getUser();
            } else {
              this.loggedIn = false;
              this.loggedUser = Usuario.ANONIMO;
            }

            }, (error)=>{
          alert (error._body);
          this.loggedIn = false;
          this.loggedUser = Usuario.ANONIMO;
          parent.error = "ERROR! " + error._body;
        });
    }
```

En el servidor ...

```
HttpSession session = req.getSession(true);
session.setAttribute(Constants.AUTHENTICATION, auth);
```

y en otra peticion lo recupero

```
  public getUser(parent){


    const headers = new Headers({"Content-Type":"application/json"});
      var serviceUrl = 'http://127.0.0.1:8080/ProgramaHospitalServicios/autenticacion';
      var body:any = {
          "service":"getAutentication",
          "params": {}
      };

      return this.http.post(serviceUrl, body,{headers:headers})
      .subscribe((response)=>{
          if(response.status==200){
            debugger;
            var aux = response.json();
              this.loggedUser.id=aux.id;
              this.loggedUser.nombre=aux.nombre;
              this.loggedUser.apellidos=aux.apellidos;
              this.loggedUser.rolId=aux.rolId;
              this.loggedUser.rol=aux.rol;
              this.myguard.setloggedUser(this.loggedUser)
              this.app.loggedUser = this.loggedUser;
         } else if(response.status==204){
             alert("Se perdio la sesion");
debugger;
         }
      }, error =>{
        console.log(error);
      });



    }
```

-en el servidor...

```
AuthenticationSession auth = (AuthenticationSession) 
session.getAttribute(Constants.AUTHENTICATION);
```

Aparte en el cliente tengo

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Http, Headers} from '@angular/http';

@Injectable()
export class HttpClient {

  constructor(private http: Http) {}

  createAuthorizationHeader(headers: Headers) {
    headers.append('Authorization', 'Basic ' +
      btoa('username:password')); 
  }

  get(url) {
    let headers = new Headers();
    this.createAuthorizationHeader(headers);
    return this.http.get(url, {
      headers: headers
    });
  }

  post(url, data) {
    let headers = new Headers();
    this.createAuthorizationHeader(headers);
    return this.http.post(url, data, {
      headers: headers
    });
  }
}
```

en el transcurso se ha perdido

¿Angular 4 no mantiene las sesiones de servidor?

He observado que la cabecera del cliente no llega al servidor a veces, cuando es un OPTIONS, con POST Si

Comment: Supongo que necesitara parametrizacion

Comment: Si lo pruebo con jmeter no la pierde

Comment: Utilizo el httpModule para conectarme con angular

Comment: angular 4 es indiferente a las sesiones del servidor

Comment: Me pierde sesiones, con jmeter funciona

Comment: estas seguro? estas verificando que mantienes la session en el http de los servicios?

Comment: eso como se hace? perdon por la pregunta

Comment: puse el codigo cliente

Comment: en el header debes colocar la session para que la valide el servidor , por ello el error colocare un ejemplo https://stackoverflow.com/a/34465070/5695795

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69458/discussion-between-jacknavarow-and-carlos-guerra-cubillo).

Answer (score 1):

Deberias usar JWT para manejar token en vez de sesiones, angular es stateless, por lo que no guarda ninguna sesion - usa la que almacena el loc- angular usar Gusardianes en las rutas para verficar si el token sigue activo